# 3ds max error: "An error has occurred and the application will close"

Tags: architecture, collada, 3dsmax, fbx

HiI'm having a trouble every time I try to export my 3ds max project to FBX or DAE formatsThe program crashes and show this error:

```
An error has occurred and the application will close. No scene changes have occurred since your last save.
```

I'm using 3ds max 2012
What can I do?
I hope someone can help me.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible for us to know why.

Make sure you have all servicepacks installed and updates.
Then try with a simple file (cube or teapot), if that works then you have to go through your scene and look for anything that can cause the crash.

First try by removing all materials (just assign a default material),
then if that does not help try to remove objects.
And keep going like that until you find the problem in your scene.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating fbx. Very often the version of fbx that comes with max is outdated by the time max comes out. If you type 3ds max 2012 fbx update in google you will find it quickly.